# Regular Expression that is Eval'ed with Word Boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex, eval

I'm trying to create a bad word filter that throws out tweets that contain any of the words in a provided list, case insensitive. Only problem is that I want to do a simple encoding of the bad word list so that bad words are not downloaded to the client browser. I think the only way I can do it is by eval'ing a regular expression. Only thing is, eval doesn't seem to work with the \b's included. How do I get regular expressions r3 and r4 to work below?

```
// encoded bad word list decoded to below   
var badwordlist = 'Sam,Jimmy,Johnny';
var restr = badwordlist.split(',').join('|');

// this works
var r2 = /\b(Sam|Jimmy|Johnny)\b/i;
var ndx2 = "safads jimmy is cool".search(r2);   

// these don't
var r3 = eval('/\b('+restr+')\b/i');
var ndx3 = "safads jimmy is cool".search(r3);

var r4 = new RegExp('\b('+restr+')\b','i');
var ndx4 = "safads jimmy is cool".search(r4);

alert(restr);
alert('ndx2:'+ndx2 +',ndx3:'+ndx3 + 'ndx4:'+ ndx4 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double-escaping inside the *RegExp()* constructor:

```
var r4 = new RegExp('\\b('+restr+')\\b','i');
```

Whenever you're creating a regular expression from a string, you need to escape the escape character.  Also, don't use *eval()* to create regular expressions :-)

Comment: Ahhhh!!! yes!! worked! relatively new with JS so I'm only now starting to realize how bad exactly eval is! Thanks!

Comment: one needs to be [exceedingly careful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) when using `\b` style word boundaries in regexes.

Comment: @tchrist: I think you're comment should be directed to the OP, I was merely answering the question :-)